# Why do only some Brahmins have a tuft of hair? Is it mandatory to cut the tuft of hair before leaving India?

Tags: belief, dharma, culture, dharma-shastras, brahmins

Why is it that some Brahmins have a tuft of hair and some don't? Is it optional?

Furthermore, the great Indian mathematician [Srinivasa Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) before leaving to Cambridge University cut his tuft of hair. Why did he do this?

Is it mandatory to cut the tuft of hair before leaving India?

Comment: It's not a duplicate if you read the question...